# 19.04 | Nvidia X Server vs Intel Graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, google-chrome, video

Today I updated to 19.04 from Manjaro

The issues:

Since I booted up my machine and whenever I tried to play any video file either via Videos, VLC and even on Amazon Prime and Netflix on google chrome.

the playback seemed to tear-up or feel choppy and not smooth and fluid.

[image]

I switched from 
NVIDIA (Performance Mode)

to

Intel (Power Saving Mode)

and everything seemed to play normally and fluidly.

Comment: What is your Hardware?

Comment: Dell inspiron 7560

Comment: @TimRichardson Dell inspiron 7560,

Comment: Intel i7, 128gb m.2, 240gb 2.5, Geforce 940mx 4gb, 8gb ram

Comment: I guess you see this problem on your laptop display but not on an external monitor, can you confirm? If so you need to activate Prime Sync.

Comment: @TimRichardson prime synchronization also doesn't work. And the issue persists on external monitor through Hdmi as well

Comment: Prime synchronization is simply greyed out.

Comment: There is no GUI for prime sync, you must be thinking of something else. But if you get tearing on the external monitor, the problem is not prime sync, it only affects the internal display.

Comment: Investigate force pipeline composition, it is in the NVIDIA control panel.